# Have I evaluated this complex integral correctly?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, cauchy-integral-formula

> Let $C$ be the circle $\mid \:z \mid = 6$ traced one lap counterclockwise. Evaluate: $$\int_{C} \frac{\cos(z)}{(z+i)^3}\;dz$$

Since $\cos(z)$ is analytic, my solution was to use cauchys integral formula; $$f^n(z_0) = \frac{n!}{2\pi i} \int_{\Gamma} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^{n+1}}dz$$ where $f(z) = \cos(z)$ and $z_0 = -i$.

$ n=2$ in this case, so we get $$f''(z_0) = \frac{1}{\pi i} \int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^3}dz \; \iff \int_{C} \frac{f(z)}{(z-z_0)^3}dz =  f''(z_0) \pi i$$

$f''(z_0)= -\cos(-i) = -\cos(i)$

$\therefore \int_{C} \frac{\cos(z)}{(z+i)^3}dz =-\cos(i) \pi i$

Just wanted to make sure this is correct.

Comment: Looks good! I would also mention the fact that  $z_0$ is inside the circle $|z|=6$ so we can use the Cauchy integral formula.

Comment: Thank you! Yes of course, forgot to mention that part.